# Facebook Graph API test user missing email

Tags: android, facebook, testing, facebook-graph-api, facebook-test-users

For my Android unit tests, I use the Facebook Graph API to create test-users and then I log in Facebook with email and password.

**Since 2021-02-26**, I don't get the test-user's email when I create one with the Facebook API.
For example :

```
POST APP_ID/accounts/test-users
```

Returns :

```
{
  "id": "USER_ID",
  "access_token": "SUPER_LONG_ACCESS_TOKEN",
  "login_url": "LOGIN_URL",
  "password": "USER_PASSWORD"
}
```

So the email is missing now, when I check my user with :

```
GET /USER_ID (and user's access token)
```

Returns :

```
{
  "name": "FIRSTNAME LASTNAME",
  "id": "USER_ID"
}
```

I checked and my user's have the "email" permission, I also tried my get with "fields=email" but  it never returns the email anymore.

So how to get test-user's email from graph API,as before ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appear that it is working now (April 2021), the facebook account is created with an email so my tests are running correctly now.